# sharepoint 2013 installation on windows 8

Tags: sharepoint-server, installation, prerequisites

I tried installing prerequisite installer.am getting the configuration error for application server role,web server role.
so i have tried installing rsat on windows 8(already language pack installed) but continuosly showing seraching for updates.how can i proceed further?Is there any way that server manager alone can be installed without the need to install the whole rsat

Comment: Internet is connected to your machine?

Comment: May be this link will help you: http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2014/08/21/guest-blog-by-jonas-nilsson-install-sharepoint-2013-on-windows-7-8-8-1.aspx

Comment: Which errors it gives?

Comment: for application server role,getting"searching for updates on this computer".Its never ending.

Comment: for appfabric installation getting the error at hosting services,cache while installing

Comment: Have you turned on all the required features from Windows Features?

Comment: yes,still getting same issues

Answer (score 0):

1st thing, it is not supported and you will see the issues all the time even you are able to install the Sp 2013 on windows 8. I would highly recommend to create a VM on Windows 8 and install the SharePoint there.

But if you want [Here is guide](http://www.disruptivei.com/Blogg/Inl%C3%A4gg/6/Install-SharePoint-2013-on-Windows-7-8-8-1), i outline few pre steps here.

- First make sure you have installed IIS on your machine. It isn't installed by default.
- make sure you have HTTP Activation AND TCP Activation installed (.NET
  Framework 4.5 Advanced Services/WCF Services).
- The standalone installer won't run on Win8 you install WIF
  from "Turn Windows features on or off".
- Make sure that the Net. Tcp Listener Adapter service and Net. Tcp
  Port Sharing Service are both configured to start automatically.

Comment: but for the prerequisite installer to be launched.first of all the remote server administration tools pack must be installed which is not happening and showing "searching for updates"always

Comment: But that's not mentioned in guide... what is os version?

Comment: windows 8 version

Comment: I mean home, pro or etc?

Comment: Its WIndows 8, Home